# Passing value from JavaScript to PHP using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to pass value to PHP code using AJAX.

**Javascript**

```
function countop() {
    var href = window.location.href;
    var href2 = href.split('/', 7);
    xmlhttp.open('GET', '/count.php?val_for_count='+href2[6], true);
    xmlhttp.send();
};
```

**PHP**

```
$x = $_GET['val_for_count'];
echo $x;
```

I don't get `$x` printed and I don't know why.

Comment: Before sending href2[6] as query string parameter, verify the value console.log(href2[6]);

Comment: Is it returning a proper string?

Comment: no, still getting nothing

Comment: try inspecting `window.location.pathname` instead of `href`. Will remove the domain and protocol and have less `/` to split. Sounds like you are miscounting

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new instance of XMLHttpRequest before using it:
`var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();`

And if you want to print the result of your request in your document, you can do it like this:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.body.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

First, `xmlhttp` is never declared, so your code throws a reference error.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Second, you never look at the HTTP response!

```
xmlhttp.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
    document.body.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(
            this.responseText
        )
    );
});
```

Comment: thank you for your anwser, but it doesnt work for me